# How to write Text on ImageView in android coding?

Tags: java, android, imageview, bitmapfactory

Hi I've been trying to write Numbers on Imageview. Images for N number of questions. If the user entered answer is correct, then it should be displayed with question number with tick mark image else question number with wrong mark image. I need to write the question number on the image.   My code is here:

```
    LinearLayout l_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_view_report);
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    ImageView[] imgview=new ImageView[questions.length];
    for(int i=0;i<no_of_questions;i++)
    {
                if(userEnteredAnswers[i]==correct_answer[i]){           
                    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.correct);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
                    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
                    paint.setTextSize(10); 
                    canvas.drawText(i, 5, 5, paint);

                    imgview[i]=new ImageView(this);
                    imgview[i].setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
                    l_layout.addView(imgview[i]);
                }
                else {          
                    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wrong);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
                    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
                    paint.setTextSize(10); 
                    canvas.drawText(i, 5, 5, paint);

                    imgview[i]=new ImageView(this);
                    imgview[i].setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
                    l_layout.addView(imgview[i]);
                }       
            }
```

I get this warning:

```
The constructor BitmapDrawable(Bitmap) is deprecated
```

Image doesn't showing at run time.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the easiest workaround without overriding anything would be to have a `TextView` and set its background with a `drawable` resource.

For instance:

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
// setting gravity to "center"
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
t.setText("FOO");
```

Comment: Hey thank you for ur idea. It's working!!! But I want the text to be in a particular position of the image. How to do that?

Comment: @VigneshBala I think it would be very difficult if ever possible to reference specific parts of the drawable. Of course, you can move the text around with the `gravity` attribute...

Comment: This is the easiest solution and requires the least code.

Comment: Only a genius can come up with simple solutions!!

Answer (score 4):

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) :

> BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap)
>   This constructor was deprecated in API level 4. Use BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) to ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density.

You can also create your own view (see [Android: Creating Custom Views tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) for an example) and put you image and the text in this view.

Answer (score 3):

1). Make your own layout Say Image_TextView.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/box" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#80666666" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Hello" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will make Image with Text over it.

2). Then use layout inflator to inflate this view in your parent view.

**Note :** Using layout inflator you can add other view to your parent view.

Answer (score 2):

its not possible to write text on `imageview`, but you can `extend` it to do so. Alternatively,

1. you can add an element overlapping the `ImageView` in the `layout`, and make it visible only when your condition becomes true.
2. or, you can use `textView` to display image, as a background or as a drawable to left/right..

**Ps:** however, the option 1 is easier to implement, but it will have additional rendering. so consider the other option first.

Comment: You can subclass ImageView, override onDraw and call canvas.drawText after super.onDraw. So actually it IS possible to write text on an ImageView.

Comment: @npace ... i didn't consider that, as i have suggested other ways which are bit easier.

Comment: Fair enough. Your second suggestion should be just as good, but the first one would make a redundant draw call, even though it's the easiest way to go about this.