# Tesseract cannot recognize my image correctly

Tags: captcha, tesseract

I am developing an Android app now, it needs to recognize captcha from website.

I utilize the **tess-two** to recognize captcha and follow **TrainingTesseract3** instructions to train my own traineddata (using **jTessBoxEditor** to correct characters), but it cannot recognize correctly and even cannot recognize it.

The below TIFF image is that I use to train my Tesseract, I collect many captchas and merge them into a image.

[TIFF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqoKn.png)

[The image that I want to recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Kbt.png)

For example, the expected result of the above image should be k8666, but the actual result is only 66.

Does anyone give me a help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your images using a .NET wrapper for tesseract-ocr [Tesseract-ocr .Net Wrapper by Charliesw](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract).

I got some better results like (K8EEE, K8656), i think you have to increase the text font and make it bold and i saved the image in tiff format with 96DPI resolution to get a better results than mine.

Comment: Could you tell me how to increase text font and make it bold on image in Android?

Comment: I'm not an expert with Android but these links may help you:

[How to write Text on ImageView in android coding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809801/how-to-write-text-on-imageview-in-android-coding)


[How to write text on an image in Java (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318205/how-to-write-text-on-an-image-in-java-android)